# Primeng Custom Style steps displaying as Buttons instead of a line

Tags: primeng

I am trying to implement primeng Steps in my application. I followed the examples in the documentation to create custom style Steps. Instead I am getting the standard style steps. Written style class in the .css file.

```
step1.component.html
------------------------
<div>
<p-steps [model]="items" styleClass="steps-custom" [(activeIndex)]="activeIndex" ></p-steps>
</div>

step1.component.ts
--------------------

@Component({
    selector: 'app-routing',
    templateUrl: './step1.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./step1.component.css'],
    providers: [RoutingService]
})

export class Step1Component  implements OnInit {

  items: MenuItem[];
  activeIndex: number = 1;

  constructor(private routingService: RoutingService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [{
      label: 'Personal',
      command: (event: any) => {
        this.activeIndex = 0;
      }
    },
      {
        label: 'Seat',
        command: (event: any) => {
          this.activeIndex = 1;
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'Payment',
        command: (event: any) => {
          this.activeIndex = 2;
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'Confirmation',
        command: (event: any) => {
          this.activeIndex = 3;

        }
      }
    ];
  }
}

step1.component.css
----------------------
.ui-steps .ui-steps-item {
  width: 25%;
}

.ui-steps.steps-custom {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.ui-steps.steps-custom .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link {
  height: 10px;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.ui-steps.steps-custom .ui-steps-item .ui-steps-number {
  background-color: #0081c2;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ui-steps.steps-custom .ui-steps-item .ui-steps-title {
  color: #555555;
}
```

[image: Actual Output]

Looks like styleClass is not applied. Can you please let me know how to apply custom style to primeng steps ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some good practices to remember when using primeng components.

1. Check which theme you are applying to the components. Styles will change depends on the themes you are choosing.
2. :host::ng-deep is for style isolation - i.e where the styles from one feature start interfering with the styles of another feature. To avoid shadow DOM to inherit this styles

So in your case if you want to apply your own custom styles to components

```
:host::ng-deep .ui-steps .ui-steps-item {
  width: 25%;
}

:host::ng-deep .ui-steps.steps-custom {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

:host::ng-deep .ui-steps.steps-custom .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link {
  height: 10px;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

:host::ng-deep .ui-steps.steps-custom .ui-steps-item .ui-steps-number {
  background-color: #0081c2;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

:host::ng-deep .ui-steps.steps-custom .ui-steps-item .ui-steps-title {
  color: #555555;
}
```

or you could nest under :host::ng-deep in css like below
Example

```
:host::ng-deep {
  //setting height for the honey blending panel properties
  .ui-panel-content.ui-widget-content {
    min-height: 312px;
  }
  .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid $color_iron;
  }
  .ui-chkbox-label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .ui-radiobutton-label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Glad to help you